# Inequality for fractional power norm (sectorial operators)

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, inequalities, operator-theory, sobolev-spaces

How could we prove following inequality:

$\int\limits_{0}^{l} u^{3}(x) dx \leq \sqrt{l} \cdot|| u||_{\frac{1}{2}}^{3}$

where

$ || u ||_{\frac{1}{2}} = ||A^{\frac{1}{2}}(u)||_{L^{2}} + || u ||_{L^{2}}$

and $A:H^{2}(0,l) \ \cap \ H^{1}_{0}(0,l) \longrightarrow L^2(0,l)$ is the sectorial operator $A=-\frac{∂^{2}}{∂x^{2}} $ for Banach space $L^{2}(0,l)$.